# Kafka consumer not able to subscribe from a Kafka topic (run via Spark streaming)

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api, sbt-assembly

Code to set up consumer, after creating the props object

```
val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](props)
consumer.subscribe(util.Arrays.asList(topic))
```

Code has import as following

```
package main.scala
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer
import java.util
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.{ConsumerConfig, KafkaConsumer}
import java.io.IOException
```

I created an assembly jar via sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.0" % "provided" 
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.6.0" % "provided" 
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka" % "1.6.0" libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka_2.10" % "0.10.0-kafka-2.1.1"
```

What am I missing here?

Error message:

> User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.subscribe(Ljava/util/Collection;)V

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the Scaladoc, but why can't you just do `List(topic)`? What makes you use a Java `List`?

Comment: Hello Abhijit, thanks for your reply. like how do I print , i just need to see if data is coming. do u hv code snippet which i can use here

Comment: You don't answer a question with another question.

Comment: what scala version are you using?

Comment: scala version - 2.10.5 ; i am able to run the jar as a java jar, i want to process it for spark streaming, so when i run it as spark submit and thats where i am getting this issue

Comment: What is the intention of programmatically creating a consumer in spark streaming? For streaming data from kafka using spark streaming, you should use `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream`. See: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Spark 2.2.0 and kafka 0.10.0
The problem was because of different kafka default version in spark2-submit (also spark2-shell)

I found decision [here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Data-Ingestion-Integration/KafkaConsumer-subscribe-0-9-vs-0-10-in-Structured-streaming/td-p/60161)

```
1. Before spark2-submit you have to export kafka version
$ export SPARK_KAFKA_VERSION=0.10
$ spark2-submit ...
```

Answer (score -2):

`subscribe` take input of type `java.util.Collections` instead of `java.util.Arrays.asList`.

Try

```
consumer.subscribe(java.util.Arrays.asList("topic"))
```

it should work...

Comment: no hitesh, it didnt help. I am still facin the issue.

Comment: could please add "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.10.0.0" dependency

Comment: A `List` is a `Collection`. Inheritance 101.